# mootool 1.4.2 conflict with another mootool file

Tags: mootools, conflict

I made a range slider (http://maatren.com/range_slider/range.html) in mootool but it is working fine without file "mootool 1.4.2" (http://maatren.com/range_slider/js/mootools-core-1.4.2-full-compat.js). Another mootool file is http://maatren.com/range_slider/mootools12_all_p.js and if I remove second mootool file then it stops working. But I have to use first also I can't remove first file.
Please suggest me any way to work this correctly with both the files.

Answer (score 2):

Is `mootools12_all_p.js` Mootools 1.2?

Your problem seems to be that you have two different mootools files defined, whereas you only need one. You have also developed your range slider to utilise Mootools 1.2, instead of the newer Mootools 1.4.2.

Your only option is to update your slider to replace all deprecated functionality with the proper alternatives, thereby freeing you from your reliance on the older Mootools library.

Answer (score 0):

Holy JS Nightmare Batman!

jQuery, MooTools 1.2 AND MooTools 1.4

Dude pick a lib and stick with it.

I would reluctantly suggest that you find out what is relying on moo 1.4 and degrade to moo 1.2.

OR if you have the unencrypted version of mootools12_all_p.js upgrade your moo 1.2 to 1.4.

Also when using mootools 1.4 (especially with other libs like jquery) better to use document.id instead of $ do this or update your jQuery to noConflict mode and use jQuery instead of $.

Hope this helps,
Tim

Comment: if i am not using mootools12_all_p.js file then my range slider stops working. Range slider is not working with 1.4 version of mootool.